# SDN parameterize RelationshipEntity type

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

In order to create `RelationshipEntity` I have to use the following construction:

```
@RelationshipEntity(type = "PLAYED_IN")
public class Role {
    @Id @GeneratedValue   private Long relationshipId;
    @Property  private String title;
    @StartNode private Actor actor;
    @EndNode   private Movie movie;
}
```

I have a question - is it possible to parameterize the `RelationshipEntity` type? Right now in the example above we have hard-coded `PLAYED_IN` type but I need to use many other types, like for example `DIRECTOR_IN`, `WRITER_IN` and so on. How to achieve it with SDN without introducing the separate `RelationshipEntity`  classes for this purpose?

One possible solution is to define the job type as RelationshipEntity property but I'm not sure it is a good idea because I have ~30 millions of entities and AFAIK Neo4j doesn't support indexes on `RelationshipEntity` properties... Please advise.

Comment: I assume title has another meaning than movie title, or? Because given you class above, a simple relationship would be possible if you do not need the property title. If this is not possible, ThirstForKnowledge's answer is the best you can do in this situation.

Comment: This is just the sample class copied from SDN official documentation. Also, I’m thinking on the introduction of intermediate node instead of relationship

Comment: Maybe this is more suitable for your problem. Every `RelationshipEntity` is seen from Neo4j-OGM as something "fixed" (no business logic inheritance, type changes etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about relying on an abstract class with the common basics and inherit each necessary Role from it?

```
abstract class BaseRelationship {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long relationshipId;

  @Property  
  private String title;

  [...]
}
```

and

```
@RelationshipEntity(type = "PLAYED_IN")
public class Role extends BaseRelationship {
  [...]
}
```

Comment: It will still require to define the separate class for each relationship type but I prefer to avoid it